# Adding a custom Task after approval

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, approval-process

I already added the approval Workflow to a document list

[image]

Now I want to copy the document after every approval to a RecordCenter. 
How is it possible to create a custom Task that will be executed after a approve occurs depend on this workflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can:

1. Create a copy of standard approval workflow and customize it in sharepoint designer - add step with your business logic here

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Video-Create-an-approval-workflow-in-SharePoint-Designer-2010-d7497373-964f-4470-a7d3-aa25cc84c050

2. Create workflow event reciever and do execute your logic on WorkflowCompleted event.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg749858(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Thx for your suggestion. I'am new to this workflow, so is it possible to move the spezific file to the recordcenter? Because I can only copy the "CurrentItem" and not the referenced element (document) to the rc.

Comment: I think you have to use "Send Document to Repository" workflow action. Look [this article](http://www.sharepointbriefing.com/spcode/article.php/52271_3893446_2/Moving-a-Document-to-the-SharePoint-2010-Records-Center.htm)

Comment: So I think I must create a hidden field to tell the list workflow to send the document to the record center. This can help. Thy a lot.